# Maximum probability returned much less than 1: truncated calibration curve

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, model, validation, calibration

There's a `sklearn` calibration curve [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.calibration_curve.html) which shows curves for different estimators.  I changed it to reproduce an issue I am having on a true dataset by adding class imbalance (.95,.05).  I get the following curve.

[image]

I see that for the blue curve "Mean predicted value" never goes above 0.8. Why?

Same thing here

[Austin and Steyerberg (2013) 10.1002/sim.5941](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.5941/epdf) 
[image]

Comment: Could this be because your model never produces predictions that are higher than about 0.8? You could check the maximum value in your `y_prob` vector.

Comment: Yes, I think this was the case. Realized this today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your model never produces predictions that are higher than about 0.8.

With an unbalanced data set like the one you're investigating, a linear model (high bias) will tend to be more sensitive to the class distribution: the probability that your model assigns a high prediction to a data point decreases as the proportion of the positive class decreases.

Comment: `a linear model (high bias) will tend to be more sensitive to the class distribution` can you explain why?